# Subscript out of range when dealing with CountIF over multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, countif

I have code that takes values from the spreadsheet and stores them into an array (Array named JanDates) those values are the days of every month in a year taken from a spreadsheet. I then have another array to store values from a CountIF function that counts every instance of (JanDates) in a column.

The issue is that I get a `Subscript out of Range` error when the amount of values in the column exceed the array size, but the array size is directly linked to the amount of dates in the month and cannot be changed.

Some context for the arrays in the code below. Month dates are stored in rows every 5th row, that's why I step 5 and count the columns in that row to get the amount of days in that month.

JanDates is the actual value of the dates in those rows which is used to run the CountIF.

ComLength is the amount of entries in the column (the entries are in date format).

I hope it makes sense, any support would be appreciated.

```
Dim ComLength As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim LetterSht As Variant
Dim FrstLtr As Variant
Dim JanDates() As Variant
Dim MnthCount As Long
Dim MnthDayCount As Long
Dim MnthDates As Long
Dim d As Long


LetterSht = (Array("First Letter", "Second Letter", "Third Letter"))

For x = LBound(LetterSht) To UBound(LetterSht)
With Worksheets(LetterSht(x))

ComLength = .Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If ActiveSheet.Name = "First Letter" Then
ReDim FrstLtr(2 To ComLength)

For MnthCount = 2 To 57 Step 5

    MnthDayCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Log").Range("F" & MnthCount & ":AJ" & MnthCount))

JanDates = Worksheets("Log").Range("F" & MnthCount & ":AJ" & MnthCount).Value2

ReDim FrstLtr(1 To MnthDayCount)
For d = 1 To MnthDayCount

FrstLtr(d) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("K2:K" & ComLength), "=" & JanDates(1, d))

    If d = MnthDayCount Then
    Worksheets("Log").Range("F" & MnthCount + 4 & ":AJ" & MnthCount + 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FrstLtr)
    End If
    
Next
Next

End If

End With
```

Next x
End Sub

Comment: `JanDates` is 31 columns (I don't know why you have `Redim` in there when you immediately override that). If `ComLength` is more than 31, there aren't enough columns in the array to use `d` as a column index, but I can't really see why you are using `d` to iterate the columns at all.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to use d to iterate through each value of ```JanDates``` so the stored values lines up with the days of the month. So FrstLtr will store the count for 01/01/2022 in array value 1 and so on. I want to get a count for each day in the 31 days, but I want it to count through more than 31 entries because multiple date entries are possible.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You're counting the items in the same range each time, so why are you using the number of rows as a counter? If you are checking how many times each of 31 dates appears in the 100 rows, why would you want to loop 100 times, not 31?

Comment: I made adjustments to my code, however now I'm not able to transpose the entirety of the array into my range, it only outputs the first array value in each cell of the range. Can I output the entirety of the array into the range without looping the output?

Comment: You don't need the Transpose there since you are populating a row, not a column.